# How to have audit table in PBI to count value changes in source table

Tags: powerbi

I want to be able to count the number of jobs that went from Pitch to other statuses listed (status Desc column). There is a date column called created which can be used to see when something was a pitch and when it changed to another status. I will be linking another table to the opp ID to capture what departments totals are. 
My output would be to count if an Opp ID - went from a "Pitch" to "Won" or "Lost" or is still at Pitch.

[image]

Comment: This is a challenging, but interesting problem. Can you check if my understanding is correct? (1) When filtering to January 3 on the date slicer, Opporunity 44071 should be counted as Pitch, because Pitch is the last status of this opportunity. (2) When filtering to January 8, Opporunity 44071 should not be counted in any status, because it has already completed. (3) When filtering to January 1, Opporunity 44071 should not be counted in any status, because its first history is January 2 and it has not yet started in January 1.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me on this. Yes your understanding is correct. My goal is to show what is converted from Pitch to something else (won/lost). I want to use "Pitch" as a base line. So I want to show if something moved from Pitch to "won" or pitch to "lost". So I can show for the year what have we converted. The data shown is filtered to only show data from an audit log that was entered (created) from 01/01/19. Does my explanation help? I also plan to link this data to another data using the OppID to be able to categorize by department.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to find a solution.

We need some steps of prep work to tackle this problem. First we use Power Query to extract changes of opportunity status to another table (let's call it "OpportunityStatusUpdate"). This table is basically a subset of audit logs including only records when opportunity status is updated from one to another. What is different from the original audit table is that it contains the previous status as well as the new status, looking like below. Note audit logs without status change (e.g. AuditID 233103) are eliminated here.

[image: OpportunityStatusUpdate]

This is the Power Query code to produce this table.

```
let
    Source = Opportunity,
    ExtractStausUpdates = (table as table) as table =>
        Table.FromRecords(
            List.Accumulate(
                Table.ToRecords(Table.Sort(table, "AuditID")),
                [Value = {}, LastStatus = null],
                (status, current) =>
                    if status[LastStatus] <> current[Status] then [
                        Value = status[Value] & {[
                            AuditID = current[AuditID],
                            Date = current[Created],
                            OldStatus = status[LastStatus],
                            NewStatus = current[Status]
                        ]},
                        LastStatus = current[Status]
                    ]
                    else status
            )[Value]
        ),
    Result = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        Table.ExpandTableColumn(
            Table.Group(Source, "OpportunityID", {"StatusUpdates", ExtractStausUpdates}),
            "StatusUpdates",
            {"AuditID", "Date", "OldStatus", "NewStatus"}
        ),
        {
            {"AuditID", Int64.Type},
            {"Date", type date},
            {"OldStatus", type text},
            {"NewStatus",  type text}
        }
    )
in
    Result
```

Additionally, we need two dimension tables, one date table (calling "Date of Status Update"), and the other for status. The date table has one-to-many relationship with OpportunityStatusUpdate. Status is disconnected from any other tables. OpportunityStatusUpdate is only for internal calculation so it can be hidden by end-users. The entire diagram will be looking like below.

[image: Relationship Diagram]

Then we can create a measure to calculate the desired numbers.

```
# Opporunities By Status Change = 
VAR MaxDate = MAX( 'Date of Status Update'[DateKey] )
RETURN CALCULATE(
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        SELECTEDVALUE( 'Status'[Status] ) = "Pitch",
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                -- All selected oppotunities with open and close dates
                ADDCOLUMNS(
                    CALCULATETABLE(
                        VALUES( OpportunityStatusUpdate[OpportunityID] ),
                        ALLEXCEPT( OpportunityStatusUpdate, OpportunityStatusUpdate[OpportunityID] )
                    ),
                    -- Open date is the first date of the audit log for this opportunity
                    "@OpenDate",
                    CALCULATE(
                        MINX(
                            OpportunityStatusUpdate,
                            OpportunityStatusUpdate[Date]
                        ),
                        ALLEXCEPT( OpportunityStatusUpdate, OpportunityStatusUpdate[OpportunityID] )
                    ),
                    -- Close date is the first date of the audit log with status "Won" or "Lost" for this opportunity
                    -- May be BLANK if the opportunity has not been closed at the time of data capturing
                    "@CloseDate",
                    CALCULATE(
                        MINX(
                            OpportunityStatusUpdate,
                            OpportunityStatusUpdate[Date]
                        ),
                        ALLEXCEPT( OpportunityStatusUpdate, OpportunityStatusUpdate[OpportunityID] ),
                        OpportunityStatusUpdate[NewStatus] IN { "Won", "Lost" }
                    )
                ),
                -- Select opportunities which has been opened and not has been closed yet
                MaxDate >= [@OpenDate] && (
                    ISBLANK( [@CloseDate] ) || MaxDate < [@CloseDate]
                )
            )
        ),
        SELECTEDVALUE( 'Status'[Status] ) IN { "Won", "Lost" },
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                -- Extract last status update in the selected period for each opportunity
                CALCULATETABLE(
                    OpportunityStatusUpdate,
                    ADDCOLUMNS(
                        VALUES( OpportunityStatusUpdate[OpportunityID] ),
                        "@LastAuditID",
                        CALCULATE( MAX( OpportunityStatusUpdate[AuditID] ) )
                    )
                ),
                -- Select rows where status was updated to the selected status
                OpportunityStatusUpdate[NewStatus] = SELECTEDVALUE( 'Status'[Status] )
            )
        )
    ),
    -- Make filters on Opportunity work
    TREATAS( VALUES( Opportunity[OpportunityID] ), OpportunityStatusUpdate[OpportunityID] )
)
```

Let's check if the output is correct.

[image: Result 1]

- There is one Won opportunity in January 2 because opportunity 39059 was won in this date.
- There is one Won opportunity in January 3 because opportunity 42337 was opened and won in this same date.
- There is one Pitch opportunity in each date from January 2 to January 6 because opportunity 44071 was opened in January 2 and had been in pitch until being won in January 7.
- There is one Won opportunity in January 7 because opportunity 42337 was won in this date.
- There is one Lost opportunity in January 15 because opportunity 39049 was lost in this date.

When we drill up to entire January, there are only Won and Lost, because all of 4 opportunities were won or lost by the end of January.

[image: Result 2]

Answer (score -1):

Try using the pivot table function in query editor. Pivot on OpportunityID.